# Extracting data from REST API (JSON) in ADF to Azure Data Lake

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, rest

I have ADF (Azure Data Factory) calling two REST API's in JSON.

1. Customer IDs
2. Customer Data. - Customer ID.

How to extract the Customer data (JSON2) based on Customer ID (JSON1), and store them in Parque file format in Datalake?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web activity to send your first request to get Customer IDs. Then you can create a copy data activity which source is REST and sink is your Parque file. Finally you can put Web activity's output into REST's body to send the second request.